# Rails params.require not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to implement a simple like button for a rails project without the use of ajax. I've tried everything I can think of, but it keeps coming to down to getting an error saying:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: vote
```

I get that this means that no vote parameter is being sent with my request, but at this point I don't know what else to try in order to get it to work.

```
    class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @votes = Vote.all
  end

  def new
    @vote = Vote.new
  end

  def create
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)


    if @vote.save
      puts @vote
        flash[:notice] = "Thanks for voting!"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
      puts "No"
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
  end

  def show
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
    if @vote.destroy!
        flash[:notice] = "Unvoted!"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  private

  def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(:food_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for [@user, @vote] do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'food_id', food.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit %>


<% end %>
```

---

user/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Hey <%= @user.firstname %>!</h2>
<p>Check out these dank Soups and Salads you've served up or <%= link_to "Upload some new Soup or Salad", new_food_path %></p>

  <strong>Image:</strong>
  <% @user.foods.each do |food| %>
  <% vote = current_user.votes.where(food_id: food.id).first %>
  <h3><%= link_to food.title.capitalize, food_path(food.id) %></h3>
  <p><%= link_to (image_tag (food.image.url)), food_path(food.id) %></p>
  <%= render 'shared/vote_form', :food => food, :vote => vote %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", food, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete this article?"} %>
  <% end %>
```

---

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :food
end
```

---

```
resources :users do
    resources :votes
  end

  resources :foods
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not being sent in `params[:vote]` because you aren't using the form object `f`. If you don't use the form object then they are just sent directly( try checking the value of `params[:food_id]` and `params[:user_id]`).

Try this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, vote] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field 'food_id', food.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field 'user_id', current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No, you aren't using the form object `f`, hence why they don't show up in `params[:votes]`.

Comment: Sorry, I had posted the wrong copy of what I was working on. I tried also with the block notation, but still receive the same error

Comment: @HarryB. Can you post what the value of `params` looks like after you submit the form.

Comment: I'm trying to display the button/form on my user/show page, and at this point I can't even get the user/show page to load because it now just says: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: @HarryB. I am guessing `@user` is `nil`, I can't see where you are setting the instance variable `@user` actually. You are not setting `@user` in `VoteController` anywhere.

Comment: I think @ vote is nil because the original param problem I was dealing with had to do with vote being empty. Also, on the rails console that pops up in the browser when I type in @ user, I get the user whose page I am trying access, but when I type @ vote I get nil

Comment: oh wait, I think you just need to change `@vote` to `vote` because you are passing it as a local here `<%= render 'shared/vote_form', :food => food, :vote => vote %>`

Comment: hmm that does get me past that error to a new one saying: Nomethoderror from Users#show undefined method `merge' for 33:Fixnum

Comment: @HarryB. Unfortunately, that's not enough information for me to help you with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set User in the VotesController. Also, please try to share what exactly error shows in the console, to see specific error.

**Html:**

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/vote_form', locals: {:user => @user, :food => food, :vote => vote}%>
```

> Tip:
>   if @user is supposed to be current_user then use current_user object
>   instead @user!

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for [user, vote] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field_tag 'food_id', food.id %>
    #no need to pass current_user, we are gonna use in controller
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user

def create
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
    @vote.user_id = current_user.id

    if @vote.save
      puts @vote
        flash[:notice] = "Thanks for voting!"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
      puts "No"
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
end

private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
end
```